# Replacing two words in string (PHP)

Tags: php, string

I need to replace two words with one word in string. For example my string looks like:

```
$mySentence = "abcd efg ijkl";
$replaceWith = "XYZ";
$newString = str_replace("efg ijkl", $replaceWith, $mySentence);
```

But there is no any changes.

The output should be abcd XYZ.

Comment: [Your code works.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wRZEYS)

Comment: Quick! Everyone add the same answer! :-/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it [works](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wRZEYS).

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
<?php
$mySentence = "abcd efg ijkl";
$replaceWith = "XYZ";
$newString = str_replace("efg ijkl", $replaceWith, $mySentence);
echo $newString;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$mySentence = "abcd efg ijkl";
$replaceWith = "XYZ";
$newString = str_replace("efg ijkl", $replaceWith, $mySentence);
echo $newString;
```

This outputs

```
abcd XYZ
```

Comment: Thanks! I do the same but the only difference was in two empty spaces between "efg ijkl" that I didn't notice in my code.

Comment: Can the downovotter explain the reason for downvote.I just want to know whats wrong with the answer

Comment: not the downvoter, but I would say your answer is not really an "answer" as per se. OP has the code correct, they're only not displaying it to see the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

> But there is no any changes.

There *is* change, but you just don't output it to see. You're assigning `$newString` with the replaced text, but then never displaying the new string.

So, as the people have replied, you just need to output the variable. Either by `echo` or `var_dump()`.

```
echo $newString
```

will give you

```
abcd XYZ
```

Comment: Straight to the point answer :)

Comment: I explained in my earlier post where was the problem. Not in echo $newString but in two spaces between words that I didn't notice :/

Comment: I can see that the question hasn't been edited, so it's as you posted it the first time? And you don't have two spaces anywhere. so I guess I can justify my answer. Anyway you've got your problem solved, that's what it matters :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $mySentence = "abcd efg ijkl";
 $replaceWith = "XYZ";
 $newString = preg_replace("/efg ijkl/", $replaceWith, $mySentence);
 print_r($newString);
```

OUTPUT:

```
abcd XYZ
```

Comment: Why do you use regexp for such a case?

Comment: Perhaps, so he does not have the exact same answer as User016 and will, if lucky, get some upvotes ...